# Inhaled fumes from burning IC

Tags: integrated-circuit, soldering

I inhaled fumes that came out from burning IC from a module due to wrong wiring. Are that fumes lethal and what are those fumes made up of ??

Comment: "what are those fumes made up of ??" : Magic.  The fumes are magic, and appear in the visible spectrum as 'magic smoke'. The effects on bystanders varies from individual to individual - from feelings of amusement, to total despair.

Comment: You'll probably survive, but don't make a habit of it.

Answer (score 6):

> Are that fumes lethal?

Probably not. As you might have noticed, you're still alive.

Are they healthy? Certainly not, but a single IC's smoke won't kill you.

> what are those fumes made up of?

Mostly CO<sub>2</sub>, traces of small flakes of silicon with even smaller traces of copper, aluminium, and on the less relaxing side partially burnt carbohydrates from the package, …

All in all, not something you'd want to live in for a long time, but let in fresh air and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

No those plastic and metal oxide fumes, are not "lethal" but are not certainly good. Always tinker in an open area and use a fume extractor.

Comment: Since a f ume extractor is not always feasible (at home), use a fan that blows away smoke, preferably in the direction of an open window.